How to automatically generate an Allure report after executing all feature files instead of typing in terminal as specific script?
I'm using Python Selenium Behave and Allure reports on my automation testing, my problem is how can I generate the Allure report automatically without typing a specific script on the terminal after executing all feature files?
Currently I still need to enter a script after all feature files are done executing.
All the answers I'm seeing is connected "maven" or "mvn" but I have no idea how to apply it on my own I'm pretty new to automation and I'm creating my own scenarios for a personal project.
I enter this script first to execute all feature files and generate a .JSON format report:
"behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o reports/ features"
After all feature files are done executing, I enter this script to generate an .HTML format report:
"allure serve reports"
Is there a way that I can put in my code to automatically generate an .html report?
